# How can I convert a Keynote file to another file type using Windows or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, software-rec, file-conversion, iwork-keynote

I want to take a Keynote file and turn it into a .ppt, pdf, or multiple .jpgs.

How can I do this on a Windows or Linux machine

I'm aware of free online converters that you can use, but I'm looking for something like an API or an .exe that I can use.

Comment: I assume you can't use iWork to do the conversion for you?

Comment: @Ramhound That depends. Can I use iWork on Windows or Linux, and can I write some code or a command to call the iWork processes that need to run?

Comment: iWork only works on OS X.

Comment: @Ramhound I think there's an iWork API accessible from Windows. I'm not sure if I can use this for what I want to do, though.

Comment: I am not even aware of an OS X iWork API.  I very much doubt Apple spent time to design an iWork API for an operating system iWork doesn't even work on